# NameError: name 'librosa' is not defined

Tags: deep-learning, data-science-model, anaconda, speech-to-text, library

i'm working on Arabic Speech Recognition using Wav2Vec XLSR model.
While fine-tuning the model it gives the error shown in the picture below.
i can't understand what's the problem with librosa it's already installed !!!
[image]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by creating a new virtual env and installing all the packages using pip install instead of conda

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `librosa` but haven't specified how to use it. Try importing it as a keyword. For example:

```
import librosa as lib
```

and then whenever you want to use it, use `lib` instead of `librosa`

Comment: it still give the same error : lib is not defined

Comment: @alihayen have you installed librosa? `pip install librosa`

Comment: problem solved by creating a virtual env and and installing all the packages using pip install instead of conda. Thank you for ur help. @spectre